# Regarding ttyS0 and ttyAMA0 of Raspberrypi b+

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+

Is it possible to communicate at the same time with raspberry UART(ttyS0) port Rx and Tx and ttyAMA0 (inbuilt Bluetooth) Communication?

In my current project, I am doing the serial communication of raspberry Rx(10) Tx(8) with Arduino, but I am facing problems most of the time raspberry pi Bluetooth socket down while serial or UART communication with Arduino. 
And every time I have to manually connect the Bluetooth from raspberry pi preference Bluetooth Manager? Please help me.

Thanks......

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Use /dev/serial0 for the UART.

Comment: Hi joan ,Thanks for quick reply . Could you please tell me one thing that in between Raspberry pi3 b+ and Arduino logic converter is necessary?

Comment: The Pi's GPIO are 3V3.  You must not send more than 3V3 to a Pi GPIO.